# What does the following code say in the simple way?

Tags: python-3.x

Can you tell me what this code says in the simple way:

```
board = [['' for x in range(BOARD_SIZE)] for y in range(BOARD_SIZE)]
```

Comment: Welcome to python... the language that encourage experimentation. The first think that you can do when you want try to understand a python sentence is open a console and type it: `>>> board` will tell to you more than we can do.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good advise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code creates a list of BOARD_SIZE lists.  Each of these lists will contain BOARD_SIZE empty strings.  So if BOARD_SIZE is 3 then the `board` will be:

```
board = [ ['', '', ''],
          ['', '', ''],
          ['', '', ''] ]
```

You can rewrite this code in a single line:

```
board = [['', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', '']]
```

Comment: Does it want , (comma) after each interior bracket?

Comment: Sure.  Elements in the list must be separated by commas.  I placed them on several lines just for visual representation.

Comment: Thus, I should rewrite the code as:[[' ' for x in range(z)], for y in range(z)]

Comment: You didn't finished the comment :-)  Did you wanted to ask how to write this list in a single line?  If yes, then see the updated answer.

Comment: It was my finger fault, I did finish it :)

Comment: No, you shouldn't. This is a special syntax of the "list comprehension": https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: And read the next chapter for nested list comprehensions:  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions